# What are the possible numbers of regions that 4 planes can divide space?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

What are the possible numbers of regions that 4 planes can create? 
We know that the minimum number is 5 and the maximum number is 15.
(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpaceDivisionbyPlanes.html)

Is it possible to make a generalization based on the ways the planes 
could intersect?

Comment: If I take two parallel planes and then take a bunch of orthogonal planes to them, wont that produce a lot more than 15? What am I missing?

Comment: I think he said 4 planes.

Comment: In dimension $n,$  the maximum number of regions created by $n+1$ hyperplanes will be $2^{n+1} - 1,$ caused by extending the sides of a ( regular if you like ) simplex to complete hyperplanes. 

Comment: It is not clear to me what kind of generalization is sought here. Hyperplane arrangements have been extensively studied; in particular, the face lattice of an arrangement records a lot more information than just the number of the components in the hyperplane complement ("regions").

Comment: Are you limiting the answer to $\mathbb{R}^3$ or not?  This question is rather vague and almost seems like a first or second week homework question, doesn't it?  It is an interesting question, but there's no motivation listed, no domain listed, no mention of any attempts at solving it...  And the original author of the question has not edited the question to clarify anything.

Comment: @John Jiang, I apparently do not know how to read. :/

Answer (score 4):

Actually this seems like an interesting question to me. One can easily calculate the maximum number of regions obtained by n hyperplanes:

For lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$, by induction, the maximum number of regions achievable with $n$ lines is $1+1+2+ \ldots + n$. For planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$, denote the maximum regions by $N_n$. Then one sees that $N_{n+1} - N_n = $ the maximum number of regions in $\mathbb{R}^2$ achievable by $n$ lines, hence equals $1+2+ \ldots + n$. Thus $N_n = 1+ n + (n-1) + 2(n-2) + 3(n-3) + \ldots (n-1)$.

The in-between numbers seem much more elusive. Even the version of the problem for lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ seems hard.  I found by experimenting that 5 is not achievable by any number of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ less than 4. So a natural question could be what number $n$ has the property of not being achievable by any number of lines less than $n-1$.

For the special case of 4 planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I think the correct answer is: 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15. It's clear 6,7 aren't constructible. 13 is not constructible by brute force checking all constructible numbers with 3 planes and seeing that it's impossible to add another plane to get 13.

Comment: This was  exactly what I got. I just determined how 4 lines can intersect. Lines can represent planes, so any number of regions that 4 lines can form is possible. Also, 2 times any number of regions that 3 lines can form. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Eliminating 13: if three planes meet in a line the create
6 regions; the last at most doubles that. If two planes
are parallel they make 3 regions and the others at most quadruple
it. If three planes meet pairwise in three parallel lines they
create 7 regions. A plane not parallel to these lines doubles
the number of regions, a plane parallel to them creates at four
more regions. Thus all triples of planes meet in
one point. If all planes have a point in common, the arrangement
is symmetric about it and the number of regions is even.
Otherwise we are in general position and get 15 regions.

Comment: @unknown(google): I think you are right except the ends: 5 and 15. But I feel it's not generalizable to more than 4 planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$. 

Answer (score 2):

Computing the *maximum* number of pieces into which $r$ hyperplanes disconnect the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an old little problem, easily solved by induction, and the answer is
$${r \choose 0}+{r \choose 1}+\dots+{r \choose n},$$ and it is achieved if they are in generic position. So in dimension $n$ the number of pieces as $r$ increases is asymptotically $r^n/n!$. Note also that for $r\leq n$ it's $2^r$ and for $r=n+1$ it's $2^r-1$ (so in particular in dimension $3$ the number of pieces with $0,1,2,3,4$ generic planes is resp. $1,2,4,8$ and then $15$ (not $16$ as one would guess, so this may be used as an example of fallacious argument based on analogy).