# Number of orthants intersected by a convex hull

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

I'm trying to figure out the following problem:

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be some points for some $k<n$. Let $\mbox{conv} (x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ be their convex hull. I'm looking for a tight (possibly with an example) upper bound for the number of orthants that such convex hull can intersect with (depending on $n$ and $k$).

I've figured that as the convex hull of two points may intersect with up to $n$ orthants, by induction I can bound the number of intersections of $k$ points with different orthants to be $O(n^{k-1})$. I want to prove that this bound is tight or find a tighter one, hopefully with a concrete example.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the $k-1$ dimensional simplex given by $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\cdots \alpha_k=1, \alpha_i\geq 0$. The equations $e_i\cdot (\sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j x_j)=0$ for $1\le i\le n$ describe $n$ hyperplanes that cut our simplex into several regions. Here $\cdot$ is the dot product and $e_i\in \mathbb R^n$ is the $i$-th coordinate vector.

It is easily seen that the number of orthants intersecting $\text{Conv}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k)$ is the same as the number of regions that our simplex was divided in. Therefore the question is actually equivalent to asking: "What is the highest number of regions that $\mathbb R^{k-1}$ can be divided into by $n$ hyperplanes?" The answer is given by 
$$1+n+\binom{n}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{k-1}$$
and can be proved by induction on both $k$ and $n$ (this fact is classical and has appeared on MO before, for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38267/what-are-the-possible-numbers-of-regions-that-4-planes-can-divide-space)). In particular the $O(n^{k-1})$ bound is tight.

Comment: So it is indeed $O(n^{k-1})$ and a polynomial in $n$. Given this, If we drop the requirement $n \gt k$ and observe that the answer is $2^n$ for $n \lt k$ , that determines the answer uniquely.

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz yes! I prefer not to define it in separate cases, since the polynomial evaluated at $n<k$, does give the correct value $2^n$. Really the inductive proof makes everything clear, since it shows that the answer satisfies $a_{n,k}=a_{n-1, k}+a_{n-1,k-1}$ for all $n,k\geq 1$.

Comment: It is true that the linked question has the stated result as one of the answers given. However it doesn’t answer the question asked.

Comment: Yes, the linked question is much harder and still doesn't have a satisfactory answer.